# Handling Webhook Events in Next.js: Triggering Frontend Changes in Vercel

Tags: next.js, webhooks

In my Next.js application, I'm facing a challenge where the backend receives an event from a webhook, and I need to trigger a change or perform an action in the frontend in response to this event.

The flow is as follows: webhook sends data to the app's backend, and I want the app's frontend to respond accordingly.

I'm using Vercel, and it seems that using WebSockets may not be a viable option in this context. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this functionality. Thank you!

Additional Details:

I attempted to use [next-ws](https://github.com/apteryxxyz/next-ws) for handling webhooks, but I encountered a build error even after applying patches. The author pointed out that

> WebSocket servers (and by extension Next WS) can only be used on
> servers. Vercel is a serverless platform, meaning that Next WS cannot
> work on it.

```
> Build error occurred
20:15:42.906 | Error: Next.js has not been patched to support Next WS, please run `npx next-ws-cli@latest patch`
20:15:42.906 | at Object.verifyPatch (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next-ws/server/utilities/patch.js:30:15)
20:15:42.906 | at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/next.config.js:1:27)
20:15:42.907 | at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
20:15:42.907 | at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
20:15:42.907 | at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
20:15:42.907 | at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
20:15:42.907 | at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
20:15:42.907 | at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
20:15:42.923 | Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
20:15:43.082
```

Prior to this, I also faced challenges with both socket.io and plain WebSocket implementations, but unfortunately, I couldn't get them to work either.

Backend's code: `/api/webhook.ts`

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cryptoNode = require("crypto");

const app = express();

// Middleware to parse JSON and save raw body
app.use(
  bodyParser.json({
    verify: (req: any, res: any, buf: any) => {
      req.rawBody = buf;
    },
  })
);

// Webhook route
app.post("/api/webhook", (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
  console.log("Received request with headers:", req.headers);
  console.log("Received request with body:", req.rawBody);

  const sigHashAlg = "sha256";
  const sigHeaderName = "BTCPAY-SIG";
  const webhookSecret = process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET;

  if (!req.rawBody) {
    return next("Request body empty");
  }

  const sig = Buffer.from(req.get(sigHeaderName) || "", "utf8");
  const hmac = cryptoNode.createHmac(sigHashAlg, webhookSecret);
  const digest = Buffer.from(
    sigHashAlg + "=" + hmac.update(req.rawBody).digest("hex"),
    "utf8"
  );

  const checksum = Buffer.from(sig.toString(), "utf8");

  if (
    checksum.length !== digest.length ||
    !cryptoNode.timingSafeEqual(digest, checksum)
  ) {
    console.log(`Request body digest did not match ${sigHeaderName}`);
    return next(`Request body digest did not match ${sigHeaderName}`);
  } else {
    // Do More Stuff here
    res.status(200).send("Request body was signed");
  }
});

// Start server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Frontend is something like this:

```
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function SomePage() {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    // if something happend in the backend
    router.push("/another-page");
  }, []);

  return <div className="">Something</div>;
}

export default SomePage;
```

Comment: With the `Next.js` application, absolutely ok to use WebSockets. Could you please share more details about your application setup `front-end and back-end`?

Comment: I've added more info to the post. Thank you.

Comment: Ok @Tui, I'm reading the issue and answering your question, just a moment.
Stay here, I might need some more information, I will send you a comment

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if your `backend and frontend` application architecture is separated then I suggest using `socket.io`

Secondly, let's assume you are using `socket.io`, OK?

Because `next-ws` has no separate backend implementation functionality till now, you have to stay with `next.js` ecosystem. For more: https://github.com/apteryxxyz/next-ws

The setup for the `backend` app will be

```
const { createServer }= require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cryptoNode = require("crypto");

const app = express();

// Middleware to parse JSON and save raw body
app.use(
  bodyParser.json({
    verify: (req: any, res: any, buf: any) => {
      req.rawBody = buf;
    },
  })
);

// WebSocket implementation will start from here

const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  // options like "CORS" setup etc.
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("ping", (data) => {
    console.log(`Ping user connected successfully with the data of: ${data}`);

   socket.emit("pong", "hey, I'm pong")

  });
});

// Webhook route
app.post("/api/webhook", (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
  console.log("Received request with headers:", req.headers);
  console.log("Received request with body:", req.rawBody);

  const sigHashAlg = "sha256";
  const sigHeaderName = "BTCPAY-SIG";
  const webhookSecret = process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET;

  if (!req.rawBody) {
    return next("Request body empty");
  }

  const sig = Buffer.from(req.get(sigHeaderName) || "", "utf8");
  const hmac = cryptoNode.createHmac(sigHashAlg, webhookSecret);
  const digest = Buffer.from(
    sigHashAlg + "=" + hmac.update(req.rawBody).digest("hex"),
    "utf8"
  );

  const checksum = Buffer.from(sig.toString(), "utf8");

  if (
    checksum.length !== digest.length ||
    !cryptoNode.timingSafeEqual(digest, checksum)
  ) {
    console.log(`Request body digest did not match ${sigHeaderName}`);
    return next(`Request body digest did not match ${sigHeaderName}`);
  } else {
    // Do More Stuff here

    io.sockets.emit("hi", "Your activities data, that you might be send to frontend")

    res.status(200).send("Request body was signed");
  }
});


// Start server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

More details for the advanced `socket.io` setup: `https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api`

Thirdly, install `socket.io-client` in your `frontend` app: `npm install socket.io-client` and use a HOC architecture that will be able to detect the route change event.

For example `Next.js` `Layout` architecture

Create a `layout` folder and index.jsx/index.tsx file in the application root

```
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import webSocket, { Socket } from "socket.io-client";

//If you are using TS then use interface, otherwise skip
interface LayoutProps {
  children?: JSX.Element[] | JSX.Element;
}
// const Layout = ({ children }: LayoutProps) => {
const Layout = ({ children }) => {


  // Frontend WebSocket setup will start from here to detect the backed activities
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getSocket = webSocket("Your backend app URL");
    socket.emit("ping", "Hey, I'm ping");
  }, []);

  // This useEffect will handle the backend "pong" namespace
  useEffect(() => {
    const getSocket = webSocket("Your backend app URL");
    socket.on("pong", (data)=>{
     console.log(`Pong server connected successfully with the data of: ${data}`);
    });
  }, []);


  // This useEffect will handle the backend activities "namespace"

  useEffect(()=>{

    socket?.on("hi", (data) => {
      // if something happend in the backend
      router.push("/another-page");
      
    })

    socket?.on("disconnect", () => {
       socket.connect();
    })
  }, [socket]);

  return <>{children}</>
}


export default Layout;
```

**Note:** `Frotend` application WebSocket namespace will be the same as `Backend` application namespace

Finally, create a file `_app.jsx/_app.tsx` in your root routing `pages` folder and use the Layout component with _app.jsx/_app.tsx file to wrap your main app component

```
import Layout from "../layout";

const YourApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  // Others setup or some other advanced implementation
  return(
    <Layout>
      <ComponentToRender {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default YourApp;
```

If you don't understand after reading this mass implementation, then send me a message, and we can have a meeting to set up your application architecture

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I respectfully want to point out that there are some issues with the front-end code. The `socket` is `undefined`, `setSocket` is not used, and `getSocket` is created but not used either. Also, in the backend code, there's an attempt to `createServer`, but Next.js is serverless as mentioned before.